# Does Android SDK intentionally use an old version of ProGuard

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-sdk-tools

I use the Android SDK Manager to keep all the packages updated. The current (2014-03-05) Android SDK Tools is V22.6. I checked proguard.jar in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib,and found its version is 4.7. [The latest version of ProGuard is 4.11](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#downloads.html). [V4.7 was released in 2011](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#downloads.html).
Is there a good reason for the SDK to use an old version? Should I update ProGuard manually?

I heard that if proguard.jar is updated manually, updating the SDK via the Android SDK Manager will overwrite it. Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version in the Android SDK is often lagging behind. At this time, the Android SDK contains ProGuard 4.7, while the Android Gradle plugin refers to ProGuard 4.10 from Maven Central. I generally recommend to use the latest version, especially if you have enabled optimization and if you run into any bugs in older versions.

(I am the developer of ProGuard)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I  manually updated the three ProGuard jars before seeing your answer, and finally have made ProGuard work for an app after numerous attempts in the past year or so.   I am so glad to see your answer that gives me confidence on what is finally working. I am wondering if updating Android SDK Tools in the future will replace the jars with older ones. Right now, I am using the latest Android SDK Tools (22.6).

Comment: Hi @Eric Lafortune, I'm using the Proguard.jar file to De-Obfuscated the crash log.  Should I take Proguard.jar and retrace.jar static for all android compile SDK versions or Should I override the manually updated version in any Android Gradle file?